# Android admob questions

Tags: android, ads, admob

Nothing about how to implement ads via admob into an application or anything. I'm just new to ads and it's pretty confusing to get a good grasp on how it works. I've been wanting to put out an app with ads in it but have been reading you need to initially pay at least $50 to get started? I thought it was free to ad whatever ads to display on YOUR app. Or is the $ for adding your own advertising on OTHER people's apps? I'm so confused. Someone please enlighten me, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or is the $ for adding your own
>   advertising on OTHER people's apps?

Correct. Placing Ads inside your application is free and you earn money.
The $50 is to place your custom Ads in other peoples applications.

Answer (score 1):

I never had to pay to get AdMob running. You have to pay to get a publisher account to publish your applications in google market, which I believe is a $20 charge one time.

Comment: The publisher account is for publishing your own custom ads on other peoples ads?

Comment: it has nothing to do with admob. The publisher account is for publishing applications, completely mutually exclusive from the ad networks.